# Import some of the files of a svn repository in visual studio

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, repository, visualsvn, ankhsvn

How do I import some of the directories or files of a repository in a new visual studio project while keeping the link of those directories or files to the repository?
The repository is on CloudForge. I installed Visual Studio Ultimate 2012, VisualSVN 4.0.2, AnkhSvn-2.5.12266, and TortoiseSVN-1.8.4 .